# Javascript : How can i return object type?

Tags: javascript

i'm trying to do js study these days. I made something but I found some problems. How can I fix this problem?

```
function part1(sql, controltime, headers_view, results_view, tmp){
    var timerName = "QueryTime";
    var request = new Request(sql, function(err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
    request.on('doneProc', function(rowCount, more, rows) {
        if(!more){
            console.timeEnd(timerName);
        }
    });
    var result = "";
    var header = "";

    request.on('row', function(columns) { 
        headers_view = '\n'
        results_view += '\n'
        columns.forEach(function(column) {          
            if (column.value === null) {  
                result = '0';
            } else {
                    header = column.metadata.colName;
                    result = column.value;
            }
            headers_view += header + ',';
            results_view += result + ',';
            
        }); 
        headers_view = headers_view.replace(',\n','\n').slice(0,-1);
        results_view = results_view.replace(',\n','\n').slice(0,-1);

        tmp = controltime;

    }); 
    console.log(request);
    var request = request;
    console.log(typeof(request));
    console.log('-----------------------------')
    return {headers_view:headers_view, results_view:results_view, tmp:tmp, request:request};
```

I check  [ console.log(typeof(request)) ] & [ console.log(request) ]. former type is 'object', letter request has it's own value(SQL...)

```
async function exec1(sql, controltime) {
    part1(sql, controltime, headers_view1, results_view1, tmp1);
    var headers_view1 = part1.headers_view;
    var results_view1 = part1.results_view;
    var tmp1 = part1.tmp;
    var request = part1.request;
    console.log('&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&');
    console.log(part1.request);
    console.log('&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&');
    console.log('====================================')
    console.log(request)
    console.log('====================================')
    //console.time(timerName);
    const query = await Promise.all([
        dbconn1.execSql(request)
    ]);
```

But when I checked [ console.log(request) ]. The value is 'undefined'.
Why this problem occurs? and How can I fix this problem?

**UPDATE**
request sql is below

```
Request {
  _events: [Object: null prototype] { doneProc: [Function], row: [Function] },
  _eventsCount: 2,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  sqlTextOrProcedure: " SELECT [Head],round([Avg],2) as 'TS_Avg' FROM [first_Class].[dbo].[Control] WHERE DateTime='2020-07-26 12:30:32' ",
  parameters: [],
  parametersByName: {},
  originalParameters: [],
  preparing: false,
  canceled: false,
  paused: false,
  userCallback: [Function],
  handle: undefined,
  error: undefined,
  connection: undefined,
  timeout: undefined,
  rows: undefined,
  rst: undefined,
  rowCount: undefined,
  callback: [Function],
  [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
}
```

Comment: Are you referring to the console.log inside the part1 method or the one outside of it?

Comment: Also, what is the purpose of this line? ```var request = request;```

Comment: thankyou, first 'var request = request;' line is nothing. I just trying anything i can.. without that line the same error occur. and the part1 console.log is inside the part1!

Comment: you didn't understand my question. You have two console.log statements. Both of them output the request. From which one are you getting undefined?

Comment: function part1 request has value, but async function exec1 console.log(request) and console.log(part1.request) are undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason behind request being undefined outside of the part1 method, is because, as you stated in the comments, it is an asynchronous function.

Therefore, the lines of code that execute after the call to part1, do not wait for it's invocation to finish.

In order to have the result of the invocation of the part1 method, you need to pass in success/failure callback methods to it and use them when the method part1 finishes it's execution.

Comment: Thanks tomerpacific! I try to fix the code based on your comment!